# How to auto refresh page after the success button

Tags: reactjs

I have a button that's deleting a study with mutation from graphql, how to auto refresh the page after the study was deleted ? I tried this code, maybe I did something wrong here :

```
async deletingStudy(state, studyId) {
            const result = await deleteStudy({ variables: {studyId: studyId } });
            const removeStudy = state.studies.items.filter((item) =>  item.studyId !== studyId )
            state.studies.items = removeStudy;
            return state;
        }
```

And also this one :

```
async deletingStudy(state, studyId) {
            const result = await deleteStudy({ variables: {studyId: studyId } });
            const removeStudy = state.studies.items.map((item) =>  {
                 return item.studyId !== studyId ? { ...item, status: result.data.res ) : item; })
            state.studies.items = removeStudy;
            return state;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

[How to Refresh a Page or Component in React](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-refresh-a-page-or-component-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your broader context, but shouldn't this be a case where you'd use the `setState(newValue)` part of the `[state, setState] = useState()` hook -- rather than working on and returning state itself, use `setState(newState)`? Maybe to narrow it down, work just on `[studies, setStudies] = useState(initialStudies)`

Comment: I have a component with the ui and another js file with all the functionality for that ui